# GPS accuracy in HTML5

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, gps

As part of my diploma project I faced with with a problem of getting GPS coordinates. 
I have developed a program with JavaScript and HTML5 that gets coordinates from browser.

But the accuracy of the position is very low. I use a method `watchPosition()` with timeout:`1000`

So here is my observation:

1. I run a HTML5 app on iPhone, and accuracy begins falling. (from 150 to 1500 meters)
2. Then I run a native app with maps on iPhone, like google maps, than I wait until it found my position.
3. Then I go to my HTML5 app in browser.

And now the accuracy is higher than it was (about 5-10 meters). 
What has happend? And how do I make the accuray high as it is now without running third-party apps?

Answer (score 3):

As Miha suggested, I suspect you need the enableHighAccuracy param, however, `getCurrentPosition()` sometimes gives up too soon. It will give you a location event, but sometimes, the accuracy is less than desired.

I wrote a simple wrapper for `watchLocation` that has a similar interface to `getCurrentPosition` but allows you to specify a timeout value and an acceptable accuracy.

It's on github at https://github.com/gwilson/getAccurateCurrentPosition -- here's what the call looks like:

```
navigator.geolocation.getAccurateCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {desiredAccuracy:20, maxWait:15000});
```

Translating the above options into english -- This will attempt to find the device location with an accuracy of at least 20 meters and attempt to achieve this accuracy for 15 seconds

Comment: i don't understand about geoprogress.it gives errror

Answer (score 1):

Use `enableHighAccuracy` with `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. Here is all you need to know: [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/)

Comment: I am already using it:
watchID = watch.watchPosition (updatePosition, error_callback, {enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 1000});

Comment: `watchPosition` and `getCurrentPosition` are two very different functions ;)

Comment: I must use getCurrentPosition with enableHighAccuracy, and then watchPosition?